# Public/Private Events When Querying Facebook Graph API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building an RoR application that uses the Facebook Graph API, scraping a users events via their user_access token. I'm essentially taking that user token and making a Graph call to the API, getting all the events the user has either given a rsvp, created, declined, maybe and not_replied response to the events they've been invited to. Here is my query...

```
GraphAPIEndPoint = [created, declined, maybe, not_replied]

GraphAPIEndPoint.each do|endpoint|
  data = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
  events = data.get_connections("me", "events/#{endpoint}", fields: ['id',"name","description","place","start_time","end_time","timezone","ticket_uri", "cover"])
end
```

This query gives me the desired data but I'm unsure whether I'm getting private events from the user, which I don't want. After I've received the data, I've checked some source url's in my browser, which show a Facebook default error page saying, "Sorry this page isn't available". Other Facebook url's I've tested show me their events as public events, only the ones that seem specific to a group of friends or family give me this default error page. Also, if the events were deleted by the author (which could be an answer as to why I'm getting the default error page), why am I still getting the JSON for the event?

My only assumption is that I am, and if so, what are the privacy parameters to prevent this from happening and give me only the public events?(Please no FQL suggestions)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no direct way to distinguish public events from others using this endpoint; after all, the user has granted your app permission to see them all. One possible way to check for events that are _not_ public could be to request `/event_id` using your _app_ access token afterwards, that should get you an “Unsupported get request” exception for those events that have their privacy set to anything other than public. (Although if you have to do this for a lot of users and their events, you will run into request limits with your app token pretty quickly.)

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your answer. Although, I did figure out a way to distinguish whether an events is public or private. If i go to the Graph Explorer, and instead of using the `me` object, i use the users id to query for their events. And also adding the `?field=type` gives me the events public or private status. ex. `/<some-user-id>/events/not_replied?fields=type`.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I wasn’t aware that `type` contained that information, good to know.